# LSTM model has val_acc of 1.0 after just the first epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am using LSTM to generate news headlines. It should predict the next character base on the previous characters in the sequence.  I have a file of over one million news headlines, but I've chosen to look at 100,000 of them randomly selected for speed reasons.

When I try to train my model, in just the first epoch it reaches 1.0 validation accuracy and 0.9986 training accuracy.  This certainly can't be correct.  I don't think it is a lack of data that is the issue because 90000 training data points should be more than enough.  This seems like more than your basic overfitting.  It also takes what seems to be an excessive amount of time (about 2.5 minutes for each epoch), but I have never worked with LSTMs before so I'm not sure what to expect as far as train time. What could be causing my model to perform like this?

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Import Libraries Section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dropout, Dense  
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Load Data Section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
headlinesFull = []
with open("abcnews-date-text.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        headlinesFull.append(lines['headline_text'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Pretreat Data Section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# shuffle and select 100000 headlines
np.random.shuffle(headlinesFull)
headlines = headlinesFull[:100000]

# add spaces to make ensure each headline is the same length as the longest headline
max_len = max(map(len, headlines))
headlines = [i + " "*(max_len-len(i)) for i in headlines]

# integer encode sequences of words
# create the tokenizer 
t = Tokenizer(char_level=True) 
# fit the tokenizer on the headlines 
t.fit_on_texts(headlines)
sequences = t.texts_to_sequences(headlines)

# vocabulary size
vocab_size = len(t.word_index) + 1

# separate into input and output
sequences = np.array(sequences)
X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]     
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
seq_len = X.shape[1]

# split data for validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Define Model Section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=seq_len))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Train Model Section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=128, epochs=1)

Train on 90000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/1
90000/90000 [==============================] - 161s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0493 - acc: 0.9986 - val_loss: 2.3842e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From observing the code, what I could infer is that,

- You are using space as the filler string to match the maximum
  headline length, `headlines = [i + " "*(max_len-len(i)) for i in headlines]`
- The headlines are converted to sequences and input-output split is done only after making all the headlines to the maximum length.
- So, for most of the input, the last word or the output (or last
  numeric sequence) will be the same filler and that's why you are
  getting this much accuracy even after one epoch.

Solution:

You can add the fillers at the start of the headline instead of appending at the end.

```
headlines = [" "*(max_len-len(i)) + i for i in headlines]
```

Or, add the fillers at the end of each input, after splitting the headlines into X and Y.

Comment: I decided to add the fillers to the beginnings because then they would only need to be tokenized once and it solved the issue.  Is the only reason this is better because there is the added uncertainty of where the first non-space character will be?

It still is a very slow process.  Are LSTMs inherently more time consuming than other types of neural networks because of the recursion?